# Kotlin /Android Studio error : Required Editable! found String?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hi there i am very very new to programming but this is the error I am getting. Here is my code...

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    val savedString = savedInstanceState?.getString(TEXT_CONTENTS, "")
    editText2?.text = savedString
}
```

The final savedString expression I am getting the error "Required Editable! found String?"

Answer (score 16):

Use `setText(String)`, since `editText2.text` expects an **Editable**, not a **String**.

```
editText2.setText(savedString)
```